# Problema de lógica em PHP

Tags: php, lógica

Tenho a seguinte estrutura em PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$idplan = ( empty($_POST['idplano']) ? "" : $_POST['idplano'] );
$method = ( empty($_POST['metodo']) ? "" : $_POST['metodo'] );

if ( empty($idplan) || empty($method) ) {
    http_response_code(401);
    die('{"msg": "Plano ou Método não informado."}');
}

$plans_available = array(
    array( 
        "plan" => 22, 
        "allowed_methods" => array(
            "creditcard",
            "giftcard"
        ), 
        "modality" => "mensal"
    ),
    array( 
        "plan" => 23, 
        "allowed_methods" => array(
            "creditcard"
        ),
        "modality" => "mensal"
    ),
    array( 
        "plan" => 30, 
        "allowed_methods" => array(
            "boleto"
        ),
        "modality" => "trimestral" 
    ),
    array( 
        "plan" => 31, 
        "allowed_methods" => array(
            "boleto"
        ),
        "modality" => "semestral" 
    ),
    array( 
        "plan" => 32, 
        "allowed_methods" => array(
            "boleto"
        ),
        "modality" => "anual" 
    ),
    array( 
        "plan" => 33, 
        "allowed_methods" => array(
            "boleto"
        ),
        "modality" => "trimestral" 
    ),
    array( 
        "plan" => 34, 
        "allowed_methods" => array(
            "boleto"
        ),
        "modality" => "semestral" 
    ),
    array( 
        "plan" => 35, 
        "allowed_methods" => array(
            "boleto"
        ),
        "modality" => "anual" 
    )
);

$found = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($plans_available); $i++){
    // Teste condicional
    if ($plans_available[$i]["plan"] == $idplan && in_array($method, $plans_available[$i]["allowed_methods"])){
        $found = 1;
    }
}
if(!$found){
    http_response_code(401);
    die('{"msg": "Plano não encontrado."}');
}
die("encontrado!");
?>
```

---

Tentei criar uma lógica que verificasse o seguinte:

Se a modalidade for informada, deve-se testar se condiz com o plano informado, senão testar somente o plano e os métodos permitidos.

Porém eu dei uma travada nessa verificação, no código acima eu não verifico a modalidade, e funciona!

---

Tentei algo do tipo:

```
if ( $plans_available[$i]["plan"] == $idplan && in_array($method, $plans_available[$i]["allowed_methods"]) && empty($modality) ){
    $found = 1;
} else if ( $plans_available[$i]["plan"] == $idplan && in_array($method, $plans_available[$i]["allowed_methods"]) && $plans_available[$i]["modality"] == $modality ){
    $found = 1;
}
```

Só que não condiz com o que preciso.

Comment: Não fica mais simples se fizer `$plans = array( '1' => array( "allowed...` onde a chave é o id do plano? pq ai vc vai simplesmente testar `in_array( $method, $plans[$plano_informado]['allowed_methods'] )`

Comment: O `$modality` vem do POST também?

Comment: @Bacco eu só dei um exemplo, porque na verdade o id do plano é outro :P

Comment: Editei com um exemplo do array que condiz mais ou menos com minha realidade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar simplesmente `&& (empty($modality) || $plans_available[$key]['modality'] == $modality)`.

```
$found = 0;

$get_arr_key = array_search($idplan, array_column($plans_available, 'plan'));

if($get_arr_key !== false
    && in_array($method, $plans_available[$get_arr_key]['allowed_methods'])
    && (empty($modality) || $plans_available[$get_arr_key]['modality'] == $modality)){

    $found = 1;

}

var_dump($found);
```

> /!\ O `empty()` considera que `0` é *vazio*!

[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f5800d18970f9d70d98bb521056793f69bd58c8)

Se quiser criar funções com nomes um pouco mais significativos, apenas um exemplo:

```
$plano_selecionado = getArrayKeyPlano($plans_available, $idplan);

$found = $plano_selecionado !== false
         && isMethodDisponivel($plans_available, $plano_selecionado, $method)
         && isModalityDisponivel($plans_available, $plano_selecionado, $modality);
```

```
function getArrayKeyPlano($array, $idPlano){
    return array_search($idPlano, array_column($array, 'plan'));
}

function isMethodDisponivel($array, $array_key, $metodo){
    return in_array($metodo, $array[$array_key]['allowed_methods']);
}

function isModalityDisponivel($array, $array_key, $modalidade){
    return (empty($modalidade) || $array[$array_key]['modality'] == $modalidade);
}
```

---

Próximo de "como está":

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($plans_available); $i++){
    if ( $plans_available[$i]["plan"] == $idplan
        && in_array($method, $plans_available[$i]["allowed_methods"])
        && (empty($modality) || $plans_available[$i]['modality'] == $modality) ){

        $found = 1;

    }
}
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/407b087267cdc9dad9ebbc4918bba583961aa656)

Comment: Acho a ultima forma mais enxuta e mais simples rs, mas as outras podem ficar como opção pra caso alguém algum dia queira aplica algo parecido :]

Answer (score 4):

### Use o [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)

Com essa função você pode especificar um filtro pelo plano e método e se não retornar nenhum elemento do array é porque não existe. Se precisar saber os itens do array que satisfazem a condição, basta pegar o resultado da chamada.

```
$found = !empty(array_filter($plans_available, function ($i) use ($idplan, $method)  { 
    return key_exists("plan",$i) && 
           key_exists("allowed_methods", $i) && 
           $i["plan"] == $idplan && 
           in_array($method, $i["allowed_methods"]); 
}));
```